# How can i prepopulate(tagit) the input by onclick event using tag-it plugin in jQuery?

Tags: events, tag-it, click

this is the html and js  part. So as you can see when i clicked on the class(`reply`) I have to select an option from the dropdown. I do not want that. I want to be prepopulated (tagit) when i clicked on the class (`reply`). How can i do that ? thx

```
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="js/tag-it.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>

<p class = "reply">Reply</p>

<input id="tos" name="tos" >
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

    });
    $(".reply").click(function(){
        reply_person = "AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC";
        var tag = reply_person.split(","); 
        //$('#tos').tagit('createTag', "tag");
        $('#tos').tagit({
            availableTags: tag,
            showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: anyone can help me with this ?

Comment: @Chris please help with this

Comment: Take a look at the documentation. You need to use the `createToken` event, and call that `onclick`.

Comment: can you send me some docs or post an answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're nearly there - two problems I can see.

1. You need to initialise the plug-in within `document.ready` before you add the tokens.
2. I'm not sure if you can add an array of tokens like that, or if you'll need to add them individually.

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#tos').tagit({
       availableTags: tag,
       showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
   });
});

 $(".reply").click(function(){
   reply_person = "AAAAA,BBBBB,CCCCC";
   var tag = reply_person.split(",");
   $.each( tag, function( key, single_tag ) {
       $('#tos').tagit('createTag', single_tag);
   });

});
```

Comment: you have a few errors in your script, but you gave me an ideea to manage that, thx

Comment: Great - yes, I didn't test it myself. Feel free to edit my post to correct it, in case someone finds this through Google in the future!